# Max memory you can give to java?

Tags: java, minecraft

I run a mine craft server on a 32 bit Ubuntu system if I upgrade to64 bit what is the max memory I can give to java? I want it to have about 12 gig of ram but I can't do that on 32bit

Comment: 64-bit Java runs more efficiently if you have a heap < 32 GB, but the theoretical limit for most processors is 256 TB (The virtual memory limit) The largest JVM memory size I have created was 8 TB.

Answer (score 3):

There is effectively no maximum in the amount of ram a 64-bit system can address. You will be stopped only by your computer's hardware. I don't think java has a max amount of alloted RAM, either, provided you use the right switch in the command.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit

Comment: The limit is unrelated to your hardware. It is directly related to how much virtual memory your OS supports (which I guess you can argue is related to hardware, but not in the way you meant I think).

Comment: It's very much related to the hardware -- memory isn't a "software" thing, in the sense that "software" isn't "memory".  An O/S can make some amount of memory addressable, based on processor architecture and any limitations on the physical hardware, but sooner or later, all memory pages have to either be backed by physical memory or some form of paging space.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, "hardware" includes paging / swap space, so if you actually require 12GB and only have 8GB of RAM, you'll need to be sure to have 4GB of spare swap space in order for Java to allocate additional memory successfully.

Comment: Alright, this downvote is ridiculous.

The actual limit is determined by available physical memory, paging space, and any resource limits on the user's process.  It isn't "essentially unlimited" -- sooner or later a permitted page has to be allocated and backed by something.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java Tuning](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/tuning.html#section4.1.2) white paper:

> For a 32-bit process model, the maximum virtual address size of the process is typically 4 GB, though some operating systems limit this to 2 GB or 3 GB. The maximum heap size is typically -Xmx3800m (1600m) for 2 GB limits), though the actual limitation is application dependent. For 64-bit process models, the maximum is essentially unlimited.

But truth is, such a huge heap memory usage (12GB) is counterproductive. After running for a long time, the time your application spends doing garbage collection will negate the effect of having so much memory available.

Comment: That depends.  It is possible to code Java both so there is little garbage collection and so that it doesn't make your life miserable.

Comment: Someone is having a bad day?

Java doesn't allocate RAM -- it allocates memory, which can be physical memory (RAM ...) or virtual (paging space, etc.)

Comment: Oscar: So have you taken to running around and down-voting my answers?  Immature much?

Comment: I'm confused I know nothing about Linux. I just want my server to be fast, and the more ram the faster it is. What would you reccomend? I run an i5 2400 processor.

Comment: @AustinUlmer first, profile. You can't make assumptions about your particular setup until you measure it. Just be aware that making available loads of memory to your application isn't _necessarily_ a good thing, you need to strike a balance between the memory allocated to the JVM and the time the GC is going to spend running. It also depends on how good is the memory management in your application, and if there are any memory leaks.